# save pointer to variable with gdb script

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I using gdb script to print some char** like:

`print *(char**) $r0`

I want to save the address to variable that I can use that address in the next breakpoint

How can I do that using gdb-script or gdb-python ?

For example

```
b *BREAK_POINT_1
commands
set ADDR = *(char**) $r0
c
end

b *BREAK_POINT_2
commands
x/100x ADDR
c
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to save the address to variable that I can use that address in the next breakpoint

```
(gdb) set var $addr = (char*)0x1234
(gdb) p $addr
$1 = 0x1234 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1234>
```

So your case, you want:

```
(gdb) set var $ADDR = *(char**) $r0
```

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html).

Comment: And how can I set watch about this variable ?

Comment: @python3.789 The usual way? `(gdb) watch * $ADDR` should work.

Comment: That doesn't work  , I can see in `info breakpoints` :  `21      hw watchpoint  keep y              * $ADDR ` I think that not resolve the address.  I just want to breakpoint when that buffer change

Comment: @python3.789 Worked fine for me. You will probably be better off asking a new question and providing a small repro with exact GDB commands.

Comment: @python3.789 The fact that GDB was able to set **hw** watchpoint indicates that it _did_ resolve the address.